# Setting laptop leds in Linux

Tags: linux, laptop, keyboard, led

I have installed Arch Linux on my laptop. Controlling ALSA using the hardware audio keys works fine using Openbox shortcuts. I only need to make the mute button lights up, like it does in Windows.

How do I set e.g. the mute button LED on my Packard Bell TJ72 laptop?

I know that it may be difficult to give me an exact answer, but a pointer to a known method for seting special laptop keyboard LEDs (mute, WiFi, email) will count as the correct answer if it helps me achieve my goal.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need a pointer, then looking for `leds` somewhere under `/sys` might be the place to start. `find /sys -name 'led*'` and it should be easy to find your way around from there.